# sql join error on missing data in joined table

Tags: php, mysql

table colors

```
    id
    value
    name
```

table covers

```
    id
    headline_de
    headline_en
    subline_de
    subline_en
    backgroundcolor_id
    foregroundcolor_id
```

sql query

```
    select covers.*,
    c1.name AS backgroundcolor_name,
    c1.value AS backgroundcolor_value,
    c2.name AS foregroundcolor_name, 
    c2.value AS foregroundcolor_value
    from covers
    join colors AS c1 on covers.backgroundcolor_id = c1.id
    join colors AS c2 on covers.foregroundcolor_id = c2.id
```

**what this does ?**

i store some colors with names in the table "colors". then i store some english/german headline+subline and define a background and foreground color in the table "covers".
the query now joins the right values from "colors" table - works perfect.

**what i need to improve**

when i delete any color, so the id of the color is missing - the query pops up a PHP error OR simply dont show the row with a missing color id.

but of cause i want to KEEP the sql result of a cover - so i can display the cover no matter if i have a background/foreground color. is there a way to check in the query if color not exist > replace with a fix value to prevent a PHP error or a missing row result for affected covers with missing color ids ?

Answer (score 1):

**Left joins** return everything from the left side of the join and everything from right where a match is found if no match is found the left side of the join is returned and null is returned from the right.

Answer (score 0):

no need to write `as on colors AS c1`

```
select covers.*,
        c1.name AS backgroundcolor_name,
        c1.value AS backgroundcolor_value,
        c2.name AS foregroundcolor_name, 
        c2.value AS foregroundcolor_value
        from covers
        join colors c1 on covers.backgroundcolor_id = c1.id
        join colors c2 on covers.foregroundcolor_id = c2.id
```